Dual basis of proper subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$
Let $W\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a proper $r$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let the columns of the following matrix provide a basis for it:
\begin{equation}
F = \begin{bmatrix} 
| & & | \\
f_1 & \ldots & f_r \\
| & & |\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}.
\end{equation}
A set $f^1,\ldots,f^r:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ biorthogonal to $F$ satisfies $f^i(f_j) = \delta^i_j$. An element $\omega\in(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\omega(y) = x^Ty, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}
Then the matrix representation of the set biorthogonal to the columns of $F$ is made up of the rows of $F^{-}$, where $F^-$ is a generalized inverse, since $F^-F = I_r$. Let the singular value decomposition of $F$ be $F=\begin{bmatrix} U_{W} & U_{W^{\perp}} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} V^T$, then any generalized inverse has the form $F^{-} = V\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11}^{-1} & X \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} U_{W} & U_{W^{\perp}} \end{bmatrix}^T$ for any $X\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times (n-r)}$. Then I can take $f^i(v) = ((F^-)^i)v$, where $(F^-)^i$ is the $i$-th row of $F^{-}$.
The above suggests that I have infinitely many biorthogonal sets as long as $r<n$. Are all of those dual bases to $F$, or do I need to take specifically the rows of the Moore-Penrose inverse $F^+ = V\begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11}^{-1} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} U_{W} & U_{W^{\perp}} \end{bmatrix}^T$ for $(f^1,\ldots,f^r)$ to be the dual basis? Also $FF^+$ is an orthogonal projector on $W$ while $FF^-$ for $F^-\ne F^+$ is an oblique projector on $W$. My question is whether I am missing some condition such as $f^j(y) = 0$ for $y\not \in W$, or whether any of the biorthogonal sets satisfies the definition of dual basis, i.e., whether I can take any $F^-$.
I realize that all of those restricted to $W^*$ reduce to $F^-|_{W} = V\Sigma_{11}^{-1} U_{W}$ which is unique.
